# My screen is not updated on pressing Hot restart in Flutter, I have to press Hot reload again

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make an API call and getting a List of JSON objects in return. Using this JSON data, I am trying to create a custom widget. The code works fine, the widgets are made but I need to manually Hot Reload after a successful build to actually render those cards on the screen.

This is where I am trying to make my custom widget.

```
import 'dart:collection';

import 'package:beyond_static_app/screens/allTheBrains/projectBrain.dart';
import 'package:beyond_static_app/screens/profileCards/cardContent.dart';
import 'package:beyond_static_app/screens/profileCards/reusableCard.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CardCreator {
  late List<Widget> cards = [];

  Future<List> getAllCards() async {
    var projects = await ProjectOptions().getProjects();
    int length = projects.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      LinkedHashMap project = projects[i];
      int id = project['id'] as int;
      String projectName = project['ProjectName'] as String;
      cards.add(
        ReusableCard(
          colour: Color(0xFF7D00B5),
          cardChild: CardContent(
            title: projectName,
            state: 'active',
          ),
          id: id,
        ),
      );
    }
    print(cards);
    return cards;
  }

  CardCreator() {
    this.getAllCards();
  }
}
```

This where I am trying to display the List of custom widgets, but I have to manually Hot Reload it   every time I want to see them on the screen.

```
import 'package:beyond_static_app/screens/allTheBrains/projectCards.dart';
import 'package:beyond_static_app/screens/dashboardCards/blueCard.dart';
import 'package:beyond_static_app/screens/dashboardCards/purpleCard.dart';
import 'package:beyond_static_app/screens/dashboardCards/userCard.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dashboardCards/bottomCard.dart';
import 'package:beyond_static_app/screens/dashboardCards/createNewCard.dart';

class DashBoard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DashBoardState createState() => _DashBoardState();
}

class _DashBoardState extends State<DashBoard> {
  CardCreator cc = CardCreator();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
          child: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                  [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    UserCard(),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                      child: NewCard(),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/new_project');
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Column(
                          children: cc.cards,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(child: BlueCard()),
                        SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                        Expanded(child: PurpleCard()),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    // SizedBox(
                    //   height: 10,
                    // ),
                    BottomCard(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you didn't wait for async function return. For fixing this issue you can use `FutureBuilder` in this part

```
Container(
   child: SingleChildScrollView(
   child: Column(
   children: cc.cards,
   ),
  ),
 ),
```

Comment: `FutureBuilder<List>( future: CardCreator().cards,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot){
            if(snapshot.hasData){
            return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
            return Container(child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
            children: CardCreator().cards,
             ),),);});}},)`
**This results in an error: The argument type 'List<Widget>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<List<dynamic>>?'.**

Please help me with this.